# CORS error: Provisional headers are shown

Tags: reactjs, axios, cors, vercel, vapor

My Backend runs in Heroku, frontend, Create React App in Vercel. I try bring them under the same domain name as docs says here:

https://vercel.com/support/articles/pointing-subdomains-to-external-services

But something wrong, do you know what? I did the settings:

[image]

I have following axios settings in frontend code:

```
  axios.defaults.baseURL = "https://sp-poc.com/api/";
}
axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
```

Got error when calling backend:

```js
axios({
  method: "post",
  url: "registerEmail",
  data: {},
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    crossDomain: true,
  },
})
```

[image]

Comment: Are you running the frontend and backend on different subdomains? If so, be aware that using different subdomains implies different [Web origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin); a request from the frontend to the backend will be cross-origin, which may cause the [Same-Origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) to kick in (as you seem to be experiencing). You'll need to properly configure CORS on your backend to allow requests from your frontend's origin.